# SOLVED - Pi Zero HDMI Problem

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero

I have problem with connecting pi zero to tft screen over hdmi.

- I tested hdmi cable, config file(same sd card) and tft screen with Pi 3B,
- I tested micro hdmi adapter(which connected to pi zero) with hdmi to vga converter(Same tft screen with vga input) and working.

what can i do about this situation?

Have a nice day.

Edit:Additional information
When i connect pi zero and screen over hdmi, screen is no longer say "no signal".

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Ok, but what is the problem?

Comment: What power supply are you using on the Pi Zero?

Comment: you forgot to describe the problem that you are having

Comment: @CoderMike i used iphone adapter(1A).TFT screen feeding from another supply.

Comment: @jsotola My problem is connecting pi zero to tft screen over hdmi. When i connect no signal warning on tft screen hiding but after that totally black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my rpi zero w, the lights would light up and the monitor would not display a "no signal warning" it turns out the image on my sd card was for a rpi 2 b+ make sure your image is the right one.

Comment: Firstly thanks for answer. I downloaded latest rasbian and flashed on sd card with "rufus". Is there another distro or version of rasbian for pi zero? I think all of the change is made by dtb file between different boards. And interesting thing is it is working with VGA adapter.

Comment: If you are talking about Raspbian then there is no specific version for any Raspberry Pi model. Raspbian runs on all RasPis.

Comment: I was using motioneye os

Comment: This is happening to me, although I can SSH in to the Pi Zero W, and it displays on a 3.5" display attached to the GPIO pins - just nothing on the TV, although my Atomic Pi displays just fine with the same cable :-(

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I solved the issue with using better hdmi cable.

Comment: That is helpful to know. Perhaps you ought to post an asnwer, in order to help others?